# Help with understanding a differential equation model related to food supply per capita

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, applications

> The growth rate of a population can depend on many factors. For
> example, it can depend on the amount of food per capita $A$. If $A_0$
> is the mimimum amount of food required, one can think of the relation
> $k=a(A-A_0)$, where $a$ depends on the species and $A, A_0$ depend on
> the medium. Find the function $N=N(t)$ of the amount of population $N$
> by the time $t$ for this ecological model.

So basically, I feel like I should be able to find a differential equation that gives me some sort of relation. My main issue is that to me this statement seems nonsense, what exactly is $k$? what is $a$? it only says that $a$ is a parameter that depends on the species so I assume it means that the surplus of food depends on the species?

Also, it never says anything about proportionality or any other kind of relation, contrary to models like the logistic growth model. Could this problem be ill-stated? It was given to me by my calculus professor.

Thanks in advance

Comment: My guess would be that $k$ is supposed to be the growth rate. But that's very much a guess without further context. What source are you using?

Comment: My guess is also that _k_ is the growth rate, such as in e^kt.  The problem is saying the growth rate is proportional to the amount of surplus food per capita over their basic needs, and some proportionality constant a that is species-specific.  Some species respond more or less strongly to a surplus of food, basically.  That's my guess

Comment: My guess it that *you* who have the book or other source you got this from, need to go back and examine the context to see what $k$ might mean. $a$ on the other hand is given right there in your quote. It is simply a constant of proportionality between $k$ and the excess food per capita. Assuming the others are right that $k$ is the growth rate, saying that $a$ depends on species is simply acknowledging that some species need more surplus food than others in order for their population to grow at the same rate.